# Is there a library for sets that works with bool in Coq?

Tags: coq, type-theory

I am looking to work with mathematical sets and subsets of some universal type.
I know this is normally represented as `U -> Prop`, such as in the Ensembles library.

I was wondering if there is perhaps some representation of sets that is decidable, perhaps where sets are represented as `S : U -> bool` where we can decide for any element of U whether it is in S, or is this simply impossible?

Ideally, I would like to be able to compute, given a collection of elements of type U, the subset of those elements that are in some set S as well.

Comment: After thinking about it, I believe this wouldn't be possible without some notion of equality of elements of U, so this would need to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries to work with sets in Coq:

- [Ensembles](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html): available in the Coq standard library, the sets can be infinite, a bit clunky.
- [MSets](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.MSets.MSets.html): available in the Coq standard library, finite sets only, behaves well once extracted but the interface is clunky. See also [this paper on the implementation](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/papers/redblack.pdf).
- [fin_sets from std++](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/coqdoc/stdpp/stdpp.fin_sets.html): finite sets only, membership is decidable, includes a `set_solver` tactic for some kinds of set goals.
- [finset from MathComp](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.finset.html): finite sets for finite types, membership is decidable. See also [this guide on finset and finmap (the next item)](https://aborges.eu/finset-and-finmap/).
- [finmap from MathComp](https://github.com/math-comp/finmap/blob/master/finmap.v): finite sets for choice types (eg coutable types), membership is decidable.

Typically, once you use some part of std++ or of MathComp you are better off using all of it, in part because there is some non-trivial learning curve to these libraries (worth it, IMO).

Discussion on set libraries pops up often on Zulip ([1](https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/.E2.9C.94.20set.20library.20recommendations), [2](https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/Set.20operations.20in.20coq)).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the `finset` library of the mathcomp/ssreflect framework, if you don't know about it already: [finset.v](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.finset.html).