# How to reason about sets in Coq? - Defining Complete Lattices

Tags: coq

I defined a `Lattice` typeclass in Coq:

```
Class PartialOrder A : Type := {
    le : A -> A -> Prop;
}.

Notation "x <= y" := (le x y).

Class Lattice A `{PartialOrder A} : Type  := {
    top : A;
    bottom : A;
    join : A -> A -> A;
    meet : A -> A -> A;
    def_meet : forall a b : A, 
        (meet a b) <= a /\ (meet a b) <= b /\
        (forall w : A, (w <= a) /\ (w <= b) -> w <= (meet a b));
    def_join : forall a b : A, 
        a <= (join a b) /\ b <= (join a b) /\
        (forall w : A, (a <= w) /\ (b <= w) -> (join a b) <= w);
    def_top : forall a : A, le a top;
    def_bottom : forall a : A, le bottom a;
    exists_meet : forall a b : A, exists c : A , join a b = c;
    exists_join : forall a b : A, exists c : A , meet a b = c;
}.
```

and provided `bool` as an instance.

I would now like to define **complete** lattices, but this requires a law stating that for any set `S` (not necessarily finite, so induction on the above definition is not enough), `S` has a join and meet. How should I approach this?

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76006218/2305458) regarding set libraries in Coq.

Comment: @AnaBorges Thanks. According to that answer, the only fit would be Ensembles, since I want to model infinite sets. Why did you define it "a bit clunky"? Should I avoid it?

Comment: @AnaBorges Ah, I probably understood. I made a Complete Lattice typeclass with Ensembles, and it's pretty much impossible to instantiate it on finite sets like bool. It should not be that much of a problem in the long run, as I intend on only working with infinite lattices, but I guess that's a big limitation..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take some inspiration from what has been done into mathcomp regarding (partial) orders. See, for instance, [order.v](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.order.html).

Comment: Thanks. In general though, how do I do stuff with sets? Is there a particular library you would suggest that models arbitrary sets and basic stuff like inclusion, subset etc? I could also do that from scratch (e.g. modeling sets of `A` as `A -> Prop`), and it would probably be helpful as I'm an absolute beginner with Coq, but maybe that's a bit too much for now :)

Comment: For mathematical reasoning in Coq, you can look at the mathcomp book, available at [this link](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/); finite sets are discussed there. For Standard Coq, you can also look at [Sets](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/stdlib//Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html).